# How can I enlarge the cursor?

Tags: macos

My mom is a devoted Apple laptop user. She's 95, and she finds it increasingly hard to find the cursor, so she lets her thumb wander around on the trackpad until she can spot it moving around. While doing so, she wreaks havoc with her dock and other things. Is there a way to make the cursor larger, red, or something so she can see it better?

Answer (score 7):

Go to System Preferences/Universal Access, select the Mouse & Trackpad tab and set the mouse cursor as big as you want.

Comment: Wow, I did not know this. I'm going to use this to mess with my friends' computers from now on.

Comment: This used to be all pixellated, but in Lion+ it's a vector cursor so it still looks great!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility.
System Preferences / Universal Access / Seeing / Zoom
Now, when I lose the cursor, I do option command + to zoom into where the cursor is.  Then option command - to zoom back out again.